# Field value in a Class does not get updated with Spring Boot MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf, h2

I have a Parcel Entity, and I am populating the fields through @PostMapping. The value Volume should be gotten from a method taking in values from the agruments in the constructor.

Controller Class:

```
    @Controller
public class Controller {

@Value("#{${listOfBases}}")
private List<String> listOfBases;
@Value("#{${listOfDestinations}}")
private List<String> listOfDestinations;


@Autowired
ParcelRepository parcelRepository;


@GetMapping("/register_parcel")
public String showParcelRegistrationForm(Model model) {

    Parcel parcel = new Parcel();
    model.addAttribute("parcel", parcel);
    model.addAttribute("listOfBases", listOfBases);
    model.addAttribute("listOfDestinations", listOfDestinations);
    return "parcel/register_form_parcel";

}

@PostMapping("register_parcel")
public String registerParcel(@ModelAttribute("parcel") Parcel parcel) {
    System.out.println(parcel);
    parcelRepository.save(parcel);

    return "user/user_registration_success_form";
}
 }
```

Parcel Class:

```
@Entity
 public class Parcel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;
String length;
String width;
String height;
String weight;
String base;
String destination;
String creationDate;
String volume;
```

No args constructor:

```
public Parcel() {
    creationDate = getCreationDateAndTime();
}


public Parcel(int id, String length, String width, String height, String weight, String base, String destination) {
    this.id = id;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.base = base;
    this.destination = destination;
    creationDate = getCreationDateAndTime();
    volume = String.valueOf(calculateVolume(width, height, length));
}
```

Getters and Setters:

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(String length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public String getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(String width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getBase() {
    return base;
}

public void setBase(String base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public String getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}


public String getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

public void setVolume(String volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}

private String getCreationDateAndTime() {

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    return dtf.format(now);
}
```

CalculateVolume method that is the root of the problem:

```
private int calculateVolume(String width, String height, String length) {

    int w = Integer.parseInt(width);
    int h = Integer.parseInt(height);
    int l = Integer.parseInt(length);

    return w * h * l;
}
```

But the value volume is null in my database. Even System.out.println(); in calculateVolume does not print anything on the console, but when I run create an instance in main, all runs fine and dandy.

Any ideas on how I should proceed, or is my question too vague?

Thank you

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Parcel{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", length='" + length + '\'' +
            ", width='" + width + '\'' +
            ", height='" + height + '\'' +
            ", weight='" + weight + '\'' +
            ", base='" + base + '\'' +
            ", destination='" + destination + '\'' +
            ", creationDate='" + creationDate + '\'' +
            ", volume='" + volume + '\'' +
            '}';
}
 }
```

Comment: When you print this System.out.println(parcel); in your post controller, do you have a value for the volume? (By the way I would replace your annotation by @PostMapping("/register_parcel"))

Answer (score 0):

Change Post method in your controller
from

```
public String registerParcel(@ModelAttribute("parcel") Parcel parcel)
```

to

```
public String registerParcel(@RequestBody Parcel parcel)
```